# Is the Trump administration taking action against Trump's forecasted suicides?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, public-health

US President Donald Trump is quoted as follows:

> “You’re going to have suicides by the thousands” Trump said at a Fox News town hall. “People get tremendous anxiety and depression, and you have suicides over things like this when you have terrible economies. You have death. Probably and — I mean, definitely — would be in far greater numbers than the numbers that we’re talking about with regard to the virus.”
>   <sub>[Market Watch](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/trump-says-suicides-will-increase-by-the-thousands-if-economy-stays-closed-experts-say-hes-wrong-2020-03-25), 25 March 2020</sub>

I'm interested in if the Trump administration is taking action against these forecasted suicides, e.g., increasing federal funding to suicide hotlines.

**Question**: Is the Trump administration taking action against Trump's forecasted suicides?

I did some basic searches, but I mostly found news articles which predicted that deaths by coronavirus would far outnumber deaths by suicide.  The most relevant article I found was [*VA releases safe firearm storage toolkit in suicide prevention effort*](https://www.blogs.va.gov/VAntage/73736/va-releases-safe-firearm-storage-toolkit-suicide-prevention-effort/) (12 April, 2020), but it doesn't seem related to the coronavirus nor consequent lockdowns.

Comment: A testing of the administration's ability to reflexively suppress and conceal its own collective face-palms at their mascot's explosive free-range exaggerating.   The current coping strategy involves conflating that product with any plausible rate increase however minimal as proof of magnanamous compassion.

Comment: It is a mistake to takes Trump's off-the-cuff comments as representing policy or intention. Trump floats whatever idea pops into his head at any given moment, and forgets about it by the time he's finished speaking. Challenge him on it and he will double down on it, but I have not yet seen him *actually* try to work one of his ideas into an proper policy. We would all do a lot better merely to ignore Trump: just leave him in a FOX News corner talking to himself and let other people get on with the business of government.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley: He will either double down on it, or deny that he said it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [CARES Act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/748/text) contains the extra funding for suicide hotlines which you suggest, as well as extra funding for a few other mental health causes:

> **Substance Abuse And Mental Health Services Administration**
>
> *Health Surveillance and Program Support*
>
> For an additional amount for “Heath Surveillance and Program Support”, $425,000,000, to remain
>   available through September 30, 2021, to prevent, prepare for, and
>   respond to coronavirus, domestically or internationally: Provided,
>   That of the amount appropriated under this heading in this Act, not
>   less than $250,000,000 is available for Certified Community Behavioral
>   Health Clinic Expansion Grant program: Provided further, That of the
>   amount appropriated under this heading in this Act, not less than
>   $50,000,000 shall be available for suicide prevention programs:
>   Provided further, That of the amount appropriated under this heading
>   in this Act, not less than $100,000,000 is available for activities
>   authorized under section 501(o) of the Public Health Service Act:
>   Provided further, That of the funding made available under this
>   heading in this Act, not less than $15,000,000 shall be allocated to
>   tribes, tribal organizations, urban Indian health organizations, or
>   health or behavioral health service providers to tribes: Provided
>   further, That such amount is designated by the Congress as being for
>   an emergency requirement pursuant to section 251(b)(2)(A)(i) of the
>   Balanced Budget and Emergency Deficit Control Act of 1985.

To surmise: $425 million for the Substance Abuse and Mental Health Services Administration, consisting of at least:

- $250 million for Certified Community Behavioral Health Clinics
- $50 million for suicide prevention programs.
- $100 million for "activities authorized under section 501(o) of the Public Health Service Act" - basically general emergency-response spending.
- $15 million for tribal & native American health care.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106824/discussion-on-answer-by-cdjb-is-the-trump-administration-taking-action-against-t).